# Symfony3 @Assert\Valid not working

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I installed Symfony3 and I'm trying to validate a formchild (entity child/not mapped fields) inside a normal form, with @Assert\Valid annotation. I couldn't do it so I tried the example from the Manual:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

This example, in Symfony 3, doesn't work (at least for me).
This is where @Assert\Valid is used. How does Symfony knows in this case (example from manual) to valid the Address Entity and not any other Entity?

```
 /**
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
protected $address;
```

Has someone tried to test the example from the manual to see if it works?

Can someone please provide the working example from the manual? I don't know what I'm doing wrong..

This is my TestingController.php:

```
namespace WebsiteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use WebsiteBundle\Entity\Author;
use WebsiteBundle\Form\Type\AuthorRegistrationType;

class TestingController extends Controller
{

    public function registerAccountAction(Request $request)
    {

        $author = new Author();

        $form = $this->createForm(AuthorRegistrationType::class, $author, array(
            'required' => false
        ));

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

           echo "It works";
        }


        return $this->render('TemplatesBundle:Default:testing_registration.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

The AuthorRegistrationType.php:

```
namespace WebsiteBundle\Form\Type;


use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class AuthorRegistrationType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("firstname")
            ->add("lastname")
            ->add("zipcode", TextType::class, array('mapped' => false))
            ->add("street",  TextType::class, array('mapped' => false))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }

}
```

Author Entity:

```
namespace WebsiteBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(min = 4)
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $firstname
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $lastname
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $address
     */
    public function setAddress(Address $address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
    }


}
```

Address Entity:

```
namespace WebsiteBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Address
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $street;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max = 5)
     */
    protected $zipCode;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $street
     */
    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getZipCode()
    {
        return $this->zipCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $zipCode
     */
    public function setZipCode($zipCode)
    {
        $this->zipCode = $zipCode;
    }


}
```

This is what I get now:

```
Firstname

     This value should not be blank.

Lastname

    This value should not be blank.

Street
Zipcode
```

So: the main Entity is validated, but the inherited one (Street/Zipcode) is "ignored"..

How can I validate (with this metod, not creating Custom Validation) the child entity?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `street` and `zipcode` fields in your `AuthorRegistrationType`are not related to your `Address` entity. What is the reason you did it this way? I would create a separate form type for your `Address` entity:

```
namespace WebsiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    protected function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('street', TextType::class)
            ->add('zipCode', TextType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

Then you can embed this in your `AuthorRegistrationType`:

```
namespace WebsiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class AuthorRegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("firstname")
            ->add("lastname")
            ->add("address", AddressType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right approach to embed a form. Good answer. I think it should also include this import: `use WebsiteBundle\Form\Type\AddressType`.

Comment: We do not need the `use` statement for the `AddressType` class as both classes are in the same namespace.

Comment: And you can remove the import of `TextType` as it is not needed anymore.

Comment: Just one more question: is it a good idea to use the `SubmitType` in the form? Wouldn't it be better to do that in the controller? The form would be more flexible without it and could be easily reused in other cases.

Comment: I agree with you. But I would actually add them in the template (that is what we, by the way, suggest [in the Symfony best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#form-button-configuration)).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but it steel doesn't validate the fields from Address Entity.. The only difference is the fact that it displays `Address` before the street and zipcode fields.

Comment: Validation for the embedded `Address` object will not be triggered when the `$address` property is `null`. You need to make sure that there always is such an object in the `Author` entity.

Answer (score 1):

xabbuh is right:

I added in the controller the following:

```
$address = new Address();
$author->setAddress($address);
```

before

```
$form = $this->createForm(AuthorRegistrationType::class, $author, array(
        'required' => false
));
```

And in AddressType:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'WebsiteBundle\Entity\Address'
    ));
}
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

In your entity `Author` you have an attribute `address`, which is another entity `Address`. In my opinion this is called embedded entity, not inherited. However I'm not a native English speaker, so I cannot guarantee.

The issue is in your entity `Author`:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
protected $address;
```

This will validate the field itself, but not the fields `street` and `zipCode` from the entity `Address`. To achieve that, you should tell the validation to traverse to the entity `Address` and look up for the validations in there:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Valid(
 *    traverse = true
 * )
 */
protected $address;
```

This should do the job.

EDIT:

I couldn't see the relation between these two entities immediately in your examples. Now I see that `Author` can have only one `Address`. That means the above suggested code won't do the work for you. It is necessary only if you have a relation where an `Author` has a field `address` which is a collection, i.e one author can have many addresses.

Comment: Thanks, there is no restriction in the number of addresses that an author can have.. I tried your solution, but nothing happened..